# java наследование

Tags: java, наследование, localdate

Создайте класс, который будет представлять собой расчётный счёт в банке. На этот расчётный счёт деньги можно положить, с него их можно снять, и ещё можно посмотреть, сколько денег на счёте. Создайте два класса-наследника - депозитарный расчётный счёт, с которого нельзя снимать деньги в течение месяц

пожалуйста обьясните как сделать так чтоб при использовании метода add запускался отсчет времени и при методе withdraw отсчет времени заканчивался, чтоб подсчитать разницу и понять прошел ли месяц или нет.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Bank bank = new Bank(0);
        for (; ; ) {
            System.out.println("\nВведите операцию, которую хотите совершить: \n\nadd - внести деньги на счет \ncheck - проверить остаток на счету \nwithdraw - снять деньги со счета \nexit - выйти");
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
            String opName = scanner.nextLine();
            if (opName.equals("add")) {
                DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.YYYY");
                System.out.println("Введите сумму");
                int i = scanner.nextInt();
                bank.add(i);
                System.out.println("Внесенны деньги на сумму " + i);

            } else if (opName.equals("check")) {
                int moneyNow = bank.check();
                System.out.println("Остаток на счету: " + moneyNow );
            } else if (opName.equals("withdraw")) {
                System.out.println("Введите сумму");
                int i = scanner.nextInt();
                bank.withdraw(i);
                System.out.println("Было списано со счета: " + i);
            } else if (opName.equals("exit")) {
                break;
            } else System.out.println("Неправильно введены данные");
        }
    }
```

```
package operations;

public class Bank {
    public int money = 0;
    public Bank (int money) {
        this.money = money;
    }
    public void add (int amount) {
        money += amount;
        System.out.println("Остаток на счету " + money);

    }
    public void withdraw (int amount) {
        money -= amount;
        System.out.println("Остаток на счету " + money);
    }
    public int check() {
        System.out.println(money);
        return money;
    }
}
```

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.Period;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Calendar;

public class Deposit extends Bank {

    public Deposit(int money) {
        super(money);
    }
    public void add (int amount) {
        DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd.MM.YYYY");
        LocalDate startDate = LocalDate.now();
    }
    public void withdraw (int amount) {
        LocalDate finishDate = LocalDate.now();
    }
}
```

Comment: количество денег вы умеете сохранить, какие сложности с сохранением ещё и даты?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам не нужно запускать отсчета времени. Представьте, что у вас не один счет, а сотни тысяч. Запустите 100000 потоков для того, чтобы понять, когда истекает депозит? Все на много проще. Нужно хранить дату открытия депозита и в момент,когда деньги пытаются снять, сравнивать ее с текущей датой, определяя прошел срок депозита или нет. Кроме того, помните про принцип единой ответственности. Ваши методы класса Bank не только добавляют и снимают деньги, а еще и выполняют вывод в консоль. Вместе с тем, данные методы не выполняют своих функций должным образом. Например, в вашей реализации со счета можно снять больше денег, чем на нем лежит. Это будет препятствовать переиспользованию этих методов в дальнейшем. Попробуйте сделать так:

```
public class Bank {

    private long money;
    
    public Bank(long money) {
        this.money = money;
    }

    public boolean add(long amount) {
        if (amount<=0) return false;
        money += amount;     
        return true;
    }

    public boolean withdraw(long amount) {
        if (amount>money || amount<=0) return false;
        money -= amount;
        return true;
    }

    public long check() {
        return money;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Остаток на счету " + money;
    }
    
}

import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.temporal.ChronoUnit;

public class DepositBank extends Bank{
    
    private LocalDateTime dateTime;
    
    private final int depositPeroidInMonth;

    public DepositBank(long money, int depositPeroidInMonth) {
        super(money);
        this.dateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
        this.depositPeroidInMonth = depositPeroidInMonth;
    }
    
    public DepositBank(long money) {
        super(money);
        this.dateTime = LocalDateTime.now();
        this.depositPeroidInMonth = 1;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean withdraw(long amount) {
        return ChronoUnit.MONTHS.between(dateTime, LocalDateTime.now()) >= depositPeroidInMonth ? 
                super.withdraw(amount) : false; 
    }
    
}
```

Рефакторинг класс Main на вашей совести.